# Rendering partial views dynamically when the model is a collection type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Within a page I have a section where a collection was being checked for null and then based upon the number of items a partial view was rendered out.

```
 @if (@Model.AssociatedNarrative != null)
        {
            <hr />
            <div id="narratives" class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseNarrative">Narratives [ @Model.AssociatedNarrative.Count() ]</a></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseNarrative" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">

                                @foreach (var narr in @Model.AssociatedNarrative)
                                {
                                @Html.Partial("_NfirsAssociatedNarrative", narr)
                                }
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
```

partial view

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <p><strong>Date Entered</strong>&nbsp; @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.DateEntered)</p>
</div>
@if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(@Model.Title))
{
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <p><strong>Narrative Title</strong>&nbsp; @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Title)  </p>
    </div>
}
<div class="col-md-12">
    <p>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.NarrativeText)</p>
    <hr />
</div>
```

I changed this functionality so that the data only loads on a click event. Where I am currently stuck is in figuring out the best way to return/render a partial view to the UI when the attached model is a collection. How would I pass this to the UI so that it (partial) renders for each item? Does this need to be handled in the ajax return call or is there a way I can allow the razor syntax / mvc to handle this?

```
public ActionResult GetNarratives(string id)
    {
        //Get Narratives 
        sampleModel fm = new sampleModel();
        List<Narrative> narr = new List<Narrative>();
        narr = fm.GenerateMockBaseNarratives(4);

        return PartialView("_AssociatedNarrative", narr);
    }
```

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to best render the partial view when a collection is the returned type.

-cheers

Answer (score 0):

On first pass through, the code seems to look good, but maybe you are looking for `RenderPartial` instead of `Partial`:

```
@foreach (var narr in @Model.AssociatedNarrative)
{
    @Html.RenderPartial("_NfirsAssociatedNarrative", narr)
}
```

Comment: The foreach works fine on a load but I cant use it when I want to load the partial view dynamically via and event. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

you will need to handle the returned partial view via ajax.

```
@Ajax.BeginForm(......){ }
```

The click event will submit the form, and you can define your AjaxOptions to let the form know what you want to update, whether its Post/Get, your insertion mode etc.

Comment: I looked at the @Ajax event but the ObjectTargetID seems to be the issue. Since I am returning a collection how would I post to the ID since it needs to be unique? That seems to work well when I only need to post a partial once but what if you have multiple items in a collection?

Comment: The target ID is where you want to insert the data, you can use InsertionMode.Replace, and if you call the ajax method again it will just replace the existing partial view, otherwise you can use InsertionMode.Append, and it will append the data to the div.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a collection to render within partial view I modified the partial view to now reference a Collection type and then wrapped the contents within a for loop:

```
    @model List<MyApp.Business.Narrative>

    <!-- Associated Narrative-->
    @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p><strong>Date Entered</strong>&nbsp; @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].DateEntered)</p>
        </div>
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(@Model[i].Title))
        {
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p><strong>Narrative Title</strong>&nbsp; @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].Title)  </p>
            </div>
        }
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].NarrativeText)</p>
            <hr />
        </div>

}
```

From the base view I used `@Ajax.ActionLink` to reference the controller and method

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Narratives", "GetNarratives", new { id = 4 }, 
                            new AjaxOptions { 
                            UpdateTargetId = "narrContainer", 
                            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
                            HttpMethod = "GET" })
```

`InsertMode` along with `UpdateTargetId` allowed me to replace a div element in the DOM `narrContainer` with the partial view